# I was placed under a 72-hour psychiatric hold. Am I ineligible for TSA Precheck?

Tags: tsa-precheck, colorado

A psychiatric nurse placed me under an "M1 hold" (Colorado-specific term fo 72-hour psychiatric hold) last year. After I spent the night in the hospital, the hospitalist subsequently released me from civil commitment.

The TSA Website states persons who have been involuntarily committed are ineligible for Precheck, (https://www.tsa.gov/disqualifying-offenses-factors) but I'm not sure if the TSA counts 72-hour holds as involuntary commitment. A Reddit user on a thread about gun purchases states:

> A 72 hour hold, Baker Act, 5150, etc typically is not considered an
> "involuntary commitment" or "adjudicated mentally incompetent"...a
> judge has to rule you mentally incompetent for trial, or during your
> psych hold the psych facility went before the court and got and got a
> court order to hold you longer than 72 hours. If that hasn't happened,
> you should be able to answer "No" to [question 11F on a 4473 form]

(Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/legaladvice/comments/8x0evu/have_i_been_involuntarily_committed_to_a_mental/)

Comment: You might want to ask in the legal SE (it's really a different question- "is a  72-hour hold an involuntary commitment" under federal law?"). Seems not very clear. Nevada, for example, distinguishes between 72 hr max 'emergency' admissions and 'court-ordered involuntary commitments'.  Anecdotally one person said they had such a hold (presumably disclosed it, though it was not 100% clear) and received Precheck status.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany visas are often a question of law, yet I see them on here frequently. so i think the question would fit on either SE site